# PHP image uploader issues

Tags: php, image-uploading

I am having a problem with my PHP image uploader, as for some reason, when I test, despite selecting an image, it is echoing `NULL`, rather than the image URL. What could be a possible reason for this?

```
if (isset($_POST['add_product'])) {
    include 'connect.php';
    $prodname = (isset($_POST['productname']) ? $_POST['productname'] : null);
    $prodtype = (isset($_POST['prodtype']) ? $_POST['prodtype'] : null);
    if (empty($_FILES['prodimage']['name'])) {
        $imageURL = "NULL";
        echo $prodname."<br>".$prodtype."<br>".$imageURL;
    } else if (!empty($_FILES['prodimage']['name'])) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['prodimage']['tmp_name'], "../media/images/" .$_FILES['prodimage']['name']))
        $imageURL = "media/images/" .$_FILES['prodimage']['name'];
        echo $prodname."<br>".$prodtype."<br>".$imageURL;
    }
 }
```

The HTML code:

```
<h2>Add Products</h2>
<form action='' method="POST">
    <div class='products'>
        <h3>Product Name</h3>
        <input type='text' name='productname' class='title' placeholder='' value=''/>
    </div>
    <div class='products'>
        <h3>Product  Type</h3> 
        <div class='styled-select'>
            <select name='prodtype'><OPTION VALUE='1'>MARMORSKIVOR</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE='2'>GRANIT</OPTION>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='products'>
        <h3>Add image</h3>
        <label class="myLabel" id="prodimage">
            <input type="file" name="prodimage" id="fileToUpload" />
            <span>Select Image</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="products">
        <button class='add_product' type='submit' name='add_product'>Add Product</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

We're dealing with files here, so you need to add a proper enctype to your form.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action='' method="POST">
```

As per the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Error reporting would have helped you here.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

However, you are using 2 different path declarations here.

- `"../media/images/"`
- `$imageURL = "media/images/"`

You need to check which one exactly it is that you want to use.

- Only you know what that is and one of those is failing, or both.

If you are running your script from your root and that the folders are direct sub-folders of it, then you will need to use `$imageURL = "media/images/"`.

I.e.:

```
- root
  -> public/your_file.php
     - media
     - images
  -> other_folder_in_public
```